# SolrPhpClient not working

Tags: solr

I have a question. SolrphpClient is not working with multicore.

I have two cores in my solr say core1 and core2.
While creating object of SolrPhpClient I am using the following syntax.

$solr = new Apache_Solr_Service('192.168.12.226', '8983', 'solr/core1/' );

It's giving a fatal error...

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message '"500" Status: null_*javalangNullPointerException*_at_javaioStringReaderinitStringReaderjava50__at_orgapachelucenequeryParserQue' in C:\xampp\htdocs\solrsite\SolrPhpClient\Apache\Solr\Service.php:334 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\solrsite\SolrPhpClient\Apache\Solr\Service.php(964): Apache_Solr_Service->_sendRawGet('http://192.168....') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\solrsite\script\productlist.php(403): Apache_Solr_Service->search(NULL, 0, 15, Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\solrsite\index.php(510): include_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\solrsite\SolrPhpClient\Apache\Solr\Service.php  on line 334

Solr is working fine in admin part.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please show us more the complete code that you are using to execute your query to Solr via the SolrPhpClient? I think your connection settings are fine, this error I believe is an issue with the query that is being sent to Solr and the SolrPhpClient being able to parse the response.

Comment: Hi Paige, Thanks for your response. I am just making the object with SolrPhpClient not doing anything else right now. The error it's giving in 
http://192.168.12.226:8983/solr/core1/select?fl=ST_StockCode%2CST_ItemCategory%2CST_Stone1%2CST_Stone2%2CST_LowPrice%2CST_WebPrice%2CST_Name%2CST_ArticleType%2CST_MetalType%2CST_HighPrice%2CST_ImageFileName%2Cis_clearance%2CGroupName%2CFreePnp%2CST_ItemSize%2CST_MarketPrice&sort=ST_Name+desc&version=1.2&wt=json&json.nl=map&start=0&rows=1 .  and when I run this in url, it gives error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your url that you provided:

```
 http://192.168.12.226:8983/solr/core1/select?fl=ST_StockCode%2CST_ItemCategory%2CST_Stone1%2CST_Stone2%2CST_LowPrice%2CST_WebPrice
%2CST_Name%2CST_ArticleType%2CST_MetalType%2CST_HighPrice%2CST_ImageFileName%2Cis_clearance%2CGroupName
%2CFreePnp%2CST_ItemSize%2CST_MarketPrice&sort=ST_Name+desc&version=1.2&wt=json&json.nl=map&start=0&rows=1
```

It does not look like you are providing an actual query `q=` value in your request. I would guess that is the reason for the error... I would suggest that you start with setting the SolrPhpClient so that is passes `q=*:*` to start with.